# estimate 3-sigma limit of a skewed normal distribution with known mean/variance/skewness

Tags: statistics

Is there any method/eqn to estimate the 3-sigma limit of a skewed normal distribution, if the mean/variance/skewness is already known? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'skewed' normal dist'n. An actual normal distribution is symmetrical. // Do you mean some transformation of a normal?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the in-accurate question. Basically I have a non-linear system, for which the input is normal distributed, but the output become skewed. I am able to calculate the output mean/variance/skewness using 2nd order taylor expansion. I also need to estimate the 3-sigma limit of the output, is there anyway to do so? Thanks very much!

Comment: Just to clarify a little. The non-linear system has multiple independent input variables. All are normal distributed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Limits such as $2\sigma$ and $3\sigma$ originated because a *normal*
distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ has about 95% of its probability
in the interval $\mu \pm 2\sigma$ and about 99.7% of its probability
in $\mu \pm 3\sigma$. In particular, less than 0.00135 or 0.135% of
observations will fall above $\mu + 3\sigma.$

I don't believe it makes sense to use 'three sigma limits' for non-normal
data because the the above probability statements are not true for non-normal data or distributions,
especially not for markedly skewed ones. Thus the *purpose* of using
such 'limits' is not reliably accomplished.

What does seem to make sense is to revert to the fundamental principle.
You could approximate a 99.7% probability interval by taking quantiles
0.00135 and 0.99865 of your simulated sample. Or quantile
0.99865 to approximate a value above which 0.135% of observations 
typically lie.

---

As an illustration, the chi-squared distribution with 3 degrees of
freedom has $\mu = 3$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{6} \approx 2.45.$

The following R code generates 10,000 observations from $\mathsf{Chisq}(3).$
(You can get *exactly* the same sample in R starting with `set.seed(1234)`, as
I did.)

```
set.seed(1234);  x = rchisq(10^4, 3)
mean(x);  sd(x)
## 3.011572       # aprx 3
## 2.444897       # aprx 2.45
mean(x > 3 + 3*sqrt(6))
## 0.0152         # aprx fraction above '3-sigma limit'
qchisq(.99865, 3)
## 15.6304        # aprx quantile .99865
```

Results are as follows: If I find the upper $3\sigma$-limit, I get
 about 10.348, above which about 1.52% (*not* 0.135%) of the observations fall.
So the $3\sigma$ limit does not give the anticipated protection.

By contrast, the 99.869 quantile of $\mathsf{Chisq}(3)$ is 15.630 (*not* 10.348).
Thus 15.63 is a bound above which 0.135% of observations fall.

I do not know details of your simulated distribution. But perhaps my
chi-squared example is not outrageously unfair because $\mathsf{Chisq}(3)$
is the distribution for the sum of squares of three standard normal random
variables.

Below is a graph of the density function of $\mathsf{Chisq}(3).$ The vertical red line is located at $\mu \pm 3\sigma$; the vertical blue line cuts about 0.135% of the area from the upper tail of the density.  (In an analogous plot of a normal
density curve, red and green lines would coincide.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and illustration with chisq(3)! I guess my further question is that is there any analytical equation/approach to find the quantiles of 0.00135 and 0.99865, if we already know the mean/variance/skewness? Rather than run simulation for over thousand times?

Comment: Some books have (limited) tables for standard distributions. Most statistical software packages have PDF, CDF, and quantile procedures for the frequently used distributions. // However, I assume you don't know what distribution you are simulating (or you wouldn't be doing simulation).// I don't know how many observations you are simulating. Even if it's only a few thousand, you might get useful info from sample quantiles. I don't know a way to express quantiles of an _unknown_ dist'n in terms of mean, var, skewness, kurtosis. If you have only a few hundred simulated values, I wonder ...

Comment: ... whether sample estimates of mean, var, etc would be good enough to get accurate quantile estimates even for known distributions. For simple distn's such as exponential, I suppose yes. For more complex distn's maybe not. // If they exist, formulas for unknown dist'ns would be only approx, and the sample moments also only approx. So that does not seem a fruitful patch to explore. // I hope that with efficient code and a modern computer you could get 10,000 simulated values, // Last thought: are you _sure_ you can't derive distributional form analytically?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I don't know what distribution the output would be without running hundreds/thousands runs. // Actually that is why I'd love to have an analytical eqn to estimate, since simulation can be computational expensive in some circumstance. // Thanks a lot for your time educating me in this subject!